# How to use gcloud auth list in python

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk, gcloud-python, google-cloud-iam

We could run "gcloud auth list" to get our credentialed account, and now I want to do the same thing in my python code, that is checking the credential account by API in python. But I didn't fine it..... Any suggestion?

More information is:
I want to check my account name before I create credentials

```
CREDENTIALS = GoogleCredentials.from_stream(ACCOUNT_FILE)
CREDENTIALS = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
```

Comment: As of May 2019, this still seems to be the case. See https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/resource-manager/#authentication

Answer (score 3):

`gcloud` stores credentials obtained via

- `gcloud auth login`
- `gcloud auth activate-service-account`

in its internal local database. There is no API besides `gcloud auth list` command to query them. Note that this is different (usually a subset) from the list of credentials in GCP.

Credentials used by `gcloud` are meant to be separate from what you use in your python code.

Perhaps you want to use
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/service-accounts/keys/list, there is also API for that https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts.

For application default credentials you would download json key file using developer console https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/project?project=YOUR_PROJECT or use [gcloud iam service-accounts keys create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/service-accounts/keys/create) command.

There is also `gcloud auth application-default login` command, which will create application default credential file in well known location, but you should not use it for anything serious except perhaps developing/testing. Note that credentials obtained via this command do not show up in `gcloud auth list`.